# Wget is converting question marks to %3f, causing 404s

Tags: wget

I'm trying to use wget to flatten a microsite we have.

```
wget -P ~/wget/feature/ -mpck -o feature.log --no-parent --restrict-file-names="nocontrol" --user-agent="" -e robots=off --wait 1 -E http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/feature/
```

The css files all get 404s, because links within index.html have been converted from:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/feature/wp-content/plugins/CuteSlider/js/cute.slider.js?ver=1.1.1'></script>
```

to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/feature/wp-content/plugins/CuteSlider/js/cute.slider.js%3Fver=1.1.1'></script>
```

The question mark query indicator has been changed to %3F on the fly. Browsers and curl don't do this.

The restrict-file-names option has no effect.

This is on OS X mavericks.

How can I get wget to stop doing this? Or is something else making the changes under the covers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved the immediate problem by changing `--restrict-file-names="nocontrol"` to   `--restrict-file-names="ascii"`

However, the overall results were still pretty bad. Wget alters so many links that repair seems impractical. [Httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) gave much better results for us. There was still some editing and an .htaccess file required, but It was easily accomplished.