# wget converts fingerprints from ? into %3F

Tags: wget, static-site, static-site-generation

I want to mirror my cms-driven website to create a html-only static version. Local viewing is enabled with the `-k` option (`--convert-links`).

However, [wget](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) converts question marks `?` to percent-encoded ascii `%3F` in its html-files.

```
wget -m -nH -np -k -E --restrict-file-names=unix,nocontrol https://localhost/mysite
```

Example:

**Input** from source https://localhost/mysite:

```
<link href="/dist/css/main.css?fp=12345" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

**Expected output** from wget:

```
<link href="/dist/css/main.css?fp=12345" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

**Actual output** from wget:

```
<link href="/dist/css/main.css%3Ffp=12345.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

> Note that that the contact link now has a `.html`-suffix (`-E`) on purpose. This is correct.
> The addition of a `.css`-suffix to the fingerprint can be disregarded for this use case.
>
> Note that the fingerprint `?` is converted to `%3F`, this breaks local viewing.

How would I mirror my website and keep fingerprints intact?

Comment: Various options of `--restrict-file-names` as suggested in [23096800](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743886/23096800) did not prevent the behavior described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to search-replace with a [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# replaces all occurences of string %Ffp with ?fp in *.html files
find "/var/www/mysite" -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -i -s -r 's/%3Ffp/?fp/g' {} +
```

Be careful with the path, though.
This command iterates over all html-files in /var/www/mysite and its subfolders.